# Java Compress Multiple strings with the same rule

Tags: java, android, sqlite, compression

I'm creating an android application that needs a massive database (70mb but the application has to work offline...). The largest table has two columns, a keyword and a definition. The definitions themselves are relatively short, usually under 2000 characters, so compressing each one individually wouldn't save me very much since compression libraries store the rules decompress the strings as part of the compressed string.

However if I could compress all of these strings with the same set of rules and then store just the compressed data in the DB and the rules elsewhere, I could save a lot of space. Does anyone know of a library that will let me do something like this?

**Desired behavior:**

```
public String getDefinition(String keyword) {
    DecompressionObject decompresser = new DecompressionObject(RULES_FILE);
    byte[] data = queryDatabase(keyword);
    return decompresser.decompress(keyword);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "rules" as you call them is not why you are getting limited compression efficacy.  The Huffman code table that precedes the data in a deflate stream is around 80 bytes, and so is not significant compared to your 2000 byte string.

What is limiting the compression efficacy is simply a lack of history from which to draw matching strings.  The only place to look for matching strings is in the 2000 characters, and then only in the preceding characters at any point in the compression.

What you could do to improve compression would be to create a dictionary of common strings that would be used as history to precede each string you are compressing.  Then that same dictionary is provided to the decompressor ahead of time for it to use to decompress each string.  This assumes that there is some commonality of content in your ensemble of strings.

[zlib](http://zlib.net/) provides these functions in `deflateSetDictionary()` and `inflateSetDictionary()`.